# REGEXEXTRACT with capturing group

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I wonder if there is a way to refer to the group captured in same expression when using `REGEXEXTRACT()` in Google Sheets?

Let's say we have a sample string:
`aaa123bbb123ccc456ddd123eee123fff456ggg`

and we'd like to extract the part where some 3 digits occure at least 3 times.
Normally I would use regex like this:
`(\d{3})(?:[^\1]*\1){2,}`

but how to refer to the first group in
`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"(\d{3})(?:[^\1]*\1){2,}")`?
This one returns error in Sheets.

Comment: Just use `(\d{3})(?:.*\1){2,}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no backreference support in RE2 patterns, you need to write a custom JS function to get what you need:

```
function IS_THREE_DIGIT_REPEATING(input) {
  var rx = /(\d{3})(.*\1){2}/;
  var res = rx.exec(input);
  return res ? res[1] : "No";
}
```

It will print the contents of the first capturing group in the cell (the 3 digits that are repeating) or `No` if there is no match.

[image]

**Pattern details**

- `(\d{3})` - Capturing group 1: three digits
- `(.*\1){2}` - 2 consecutive occurrences of any 0+ chars other than linebreak chars followed with the same value as captured in Group 1.

Answer (score 1):

The way I emulated capture group behavior in google sheets is buy using REGEXEXTRACT Inline with REGEXREPLACE

For example

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "word$", "special" & REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "word$"))
```

Explained:

```
# REGEXREPLACE(my_cell, regex_to_match_word, text & capture_function)
=REGEXREPLACE(
    A1, 
    "word$", 
    "special" & 
        # REGEXEXTRACT("my_cell", "capture_regex")
        REGEXEXTRACT(
            A1, 
            "word$"
        )
)
```

References

REGEXREPLACE: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en

REGEXEXTRACT: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Without a script you may find the N-th occurrence of a group:

`=REGEXEXTRACT("aaa123bbb123ccc456ddd123eee123fff456ggg","(\d{3}\D*){3}")`

The result is:

> 456ddd

Or this [re](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/main/doc/syntax.txt) for digits only:

`(?:(\d{3})(?:\D*)){3}`

Answer (score 0):

Found this by complete accident! It's exactly what we've been looking for but it works counter to documentation/expectation.

```
regexextract(re(re1|re2|re3)re)
```

Will only return the matching `re1`, `re2`, or `re3` and not the re's outside of the parenthesis.

If you are only looking for 1 thing, you can use `re(re1)re`