# regex to match first n lines after a specific word in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: regex, spreadsheet, regex-group

In Google Spreadsheet Script, I want to capture the first 2 lines , after `i=Transactional>`
And the new line should not start with the word `STYLE`

Here's the full text:

```
<http://link.ORDERACK...&i=Transactional>
STYLE: 0043
QTY: 11 

<http://link.ORDERACK...&i=Transactional>
Striped
Cotton Rugby Short RED
<http://link.ORDERACK...&i=Transactional>
STYLE: 0042
QTY: 10 

<http://link.ORDERACK...&i=Transactional>
Striped
Cotton Polo Short
```

The regex should ignore the lines that start with `STYLE`

I used this regex:

```
var regExp=new RegExp("((i=Transactional\>\r*\n)(?!STYLE)(.*\r*\n){2})","gm");
m = regExp.exec(text)
```

However, the output includes the `i=Transactional>` as well:

```
i=Transactional> Striped Cotton Rugby Short RED
i=Transactional> Striped Cotton Polo Short
```

Tried to use `(?<=i=Transactional\>` to get everything after `i=Transactional>` but it doesn't work in google spreadsheet script (or in my code)

The output I'm expecting to see:

```
Striped Cotton Rugby Short RED
Striped Cotton Polo Short
```

Comment: See [REGEXEXTRACT with capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520869/regexextract-with-capturing-group) because lookbehinds are not universally supported in Javascript.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I'm not sure how it can help here. I tried `[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)` and it gives the text of next line (without `i=Transactional>`)  but when I add the condition regarding `STYLE` , it won't work.

Comment: So your regex fails completely? See my answer that I undeleted. Sounds like step #1 is getting your regex right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Javascript doesn't universally support lookbehinds you will have to settle for capture groups:

```
(i=Transactional>\r?\n)(?!STYLE)(.*\r?\n.*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/ovWA4L/1

Your desired data will be in capture group #2

Comment: I think OP needs to also support CRLF endings, so it should be `/(i=Transactional>\r?\n)(?!STYLE)(.*\r?\n.*)/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Noted, thanks!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks it worked, the result is in group 2 may you please give an explanation? How it captured next 2 lines, though I don't see `2` in your code?

Comment: @ZahraHnn `.*` captures an entire line, then `\r?\n` captures the linefeed and a second `.*` captures the next line

Comment: @ZahraHnn `.*` matches any 0 or more chars but line break chars, so `.*\r?\n.*` matches two lines with a CRLF or LF line break sequence in between.

Comment: @ZahraHnn Your mistake is in using `(.*\r*\n){2}` because it expects a linefeed after the line but `Cotton Polo Short` has no linefeed after it, the string simply terminates